# Duplicate class found for bouncycastle

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app and when i try to build the application it shows the error that "Duplicate class found"

```
Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.LICENSE found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.68 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.71 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71)
Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ApplicationSpecific found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.68 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.71 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71)
Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ApplicationSpecificParser found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.68 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.71 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.71)
```

I am getting this error only after adding 1 external dependency.

I have tried the below solutions:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.jetifier.ignorelist = pass
android.enableR8=true
```

But still getting the same error.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Go to build.gradle and add this within `android{}`,

```
configurations{
  all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
}
```

This will remove the duplicates.